# как запретить повторное появление элемента при условии что он уже есть?

Tags: javascript, события

```js
function push() { //добавили блок
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('class', 'box');
  document.body.insertBefore(div, box);

  var box = document.querySelector('.box');
  let currentItem;

  if (document.hasChildNodes('.box')) { //проверяем, если да то выполняем
    let mDown = e => { //mouse down
      currentItem = e.target;
    }
    let mUp = () => { //mouse up
      currentItem = null;
    }
    let mMove = e => { //mouse move
      let clientX = e.clientX;
      let clientY = e.clientY;
      if (currentItem) {
        box.style.top = clientY - box.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
        box.style.left = clientX - box.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';
      }
    }
    box.addEventListener('mousedown', mDown);
    box.addEventListener('mouseup', mUp);
    box.addEventListener('mousemove', mMove);
  }
}

// Удалить блок
let remove = () => {
  document.querySelector('.box').remove();
}
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="push()">нажать</button>
<button id="btnRem" onclick="remove()">удалить</button>
```

Comment: Проблема в том что по клику на кнопку "нажать" дважды подряд, добавляет 2 блока, как это исправить ?

Comment: например поместить строку `var box = document.querySelector('.box');` в начало функции и если box не null выходить из функции

Answer (score 0):

в jquery существует такой метод который проверяет  имеется ли на странице элемент(ы) с классом 'class'.

```
    $("element").is(".class")
```

так вот как всё будет выглядит

```
    function push(){ //добавили блок
      if (!$('div').is('.box')) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('class', 'box');
        document.body.insertBefore(div, box);

        var box = document.querySelector('.box');
        let currentItem;

        if(document.hasChildNodes('.box')) { 
          let mDown = e => { //mouse down
          currentItem = e.target;
        }
        let mUp = () => { //mouse up
          currentItem = null;
        }
       let mMove = e => { //mouse move
         let clientX = e.clientX;
         let clientY = e.clientY;
         if(currentItem){
            box.style.top = clientY - box.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
            box.style.left = clientX -box.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';
         }
     }
     box.addEventListener('mousedown', mDown);
     box.addEventListener('mouseup', mUp);
     box.addEventListener('mousemove', mMove);
  }
 return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверить, есть ли элемент можно так:

```
if (!!document.querySelector('.box')) {
  remove()
}
else {
  push()
}
```

Более стандартная практика: вывести блок в dom сразу с присвоенным ему классом

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

и дальше уже проверять наличие этого класса и менять его в случае необходимости

```
if (document.querySelector('.my-div').classList.contains('hide')) {
  document.querySelector('.my-div').classList.remove('hide')
}
else {
  document.querySelector('.my-div').classList.add('hide')
}
```

В вашем случае, если вы создаете и удаляете прямо из dom, вот такие вещи:

```
box.addEventListener('mousedown', mDown);
box.addEventListener('mouseup', mUp);
box.addEventListener('mousemove', mMove);
```

могут создавать утечки в памяти (убрали из дом, а обработчики остались). Нужно всегда следить за этим.